# Would I be able to give access to specific electron APIs safely?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

So I need to find a way to create custom window titleBar buttons that I can add functionality to safely without enabling nodeIntegration in electron. I was thinking the [preload](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window) might be what I need but I'm not sure how this works or if it would work for this.

Since I'm creating custom window buttons with HTML, CSS and Javascript, I need these methods:

```
mainWindow.minimize();
mainWindow.close();
mainWindow.getBounds();
mainWindow.setBounds(...);
mainWindow.setResizable(...);
```

This is in the renderer process so nodeIntegration would need to be enabled and would need to use remote like this:

```
const { remote } = require('electron');
const mainWindow = remote.getCurrentWindow();
```

Would I be able to use the preload option with nodeIntegration disabled to access these methods to add functionality to my custom buttons? If so, how? Would it be safe this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a preload script which provides some APIs, just like the following one:

```
const { remote } = require("electron");

function initialise () {
    window.Controls = {
        minimize: () => { remote.getCurrentWindow ().minimize (); },
        close: () => { remote.getCurrentWindow ().close (); },
        getBounds: () => { remote.getCurrentWindow ().getBounds (); },
        setBounds: (bounds) => { remote.getCurrentWindow ().setBounds (bounds); },
        setResizable: (resizable) => { remote.getCurrentWindow ().setResizable (resizeable); }
    };
}

initialise ();
```

Then, you can use the functions defined like this in your renderer process:

```
document.getElementById ("close-button").addEventListener ("click", (e) => {
    window.Controls.close ();
});
```

This reduces the risk of executing insecure code by just setting `nodeIntegration: true` on the `BrowserWindow`. However, all code which has access to `window.Controls` will be able to manipulate the window state.

Comment: Does contextIsolation or sandbox need to be enables for this to work?

Comment: [This example](https://electronjs.org/docs/all#preload) only enables `sandbox` and passes the script path to `preload` (both in `webPreferences` of the `BrowserWindow`). However, `contextIsolation` is not the worst thing to do (but not necessary in this case).

Comment: So sandbox being enabled is necessary in this case? The docs are [here](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/sandbox-option)

Comment: `preload` scripts will also work without `sandbox` being enabled. However, enabling `sandbox` is more secure because each process (including the preload script) will have its own set of APIs. Even if you do not use third-party modules in `preload`, enable `sandbox` just for forward-compatibility's sake (you might add a third-party module to preload in the future and forget to enable `sandbox`...).